# Luego de instalar PostgreSQL intento acceder a el localhost y obtengo un mensaje que indica que la pagina no existe

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7

Estoy iniciando un proyecto de pagina web la cual realizare mediante **Django**, para hacerlo mas completo usare **PostgreSQL** para el manejo de base de datos.

Ya poseo instalado el **python** con el cual ademas poseo una buena experiencia y también poseo instalado **Django**, sin embargo la instalación y configuración de **PostgreSQL** se me ha dificultado mucho o me falta por configurar algo puesto que luego de instalado el **PostgreSQL** intento acceder al `localhost 127.0.0.1:8000` mediante el navegador Google Chrome y obtengo un mensaje de no encontrado esta dirección.

Sugieranme por favor soluciones o direcciones URL que me puedan ofrecer mas información. No se si esto posee relación con mi problema pero igual les comento que no posee ningún servidor de prueba instalado en mi equipo, ademas el equipo en el cual estoy trabajando es una laptop y estoy conectado a una red inalambrica local (la de mi casa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que iniciar el servidor Django. Primero comprueba que tienes instalado Django, con el siguiente comando:

```
$ python -m django --version
```

Luegos, puedes iniciar un nuevo proyecto llamado **mysite** con la siguiente linea de comando (en Ubuntu):

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

Para correr el servidor, corre el siguiente comando:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Espero te sea de utilidad!

Exitos!

Comment: Gracias por responder Masker, eso ya lo hice y me genero una carpeta en cuyo interior se ubica un archivo manage.py y una carpeta llamada mysite que posee 4 archivos _init_.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py. Debo hacer algo mas con estos archivos antes de poder simplemente abrir el navegador escribir la direccion del localhost y acceder a el??

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, me faltó un comando, perdón!

Comment: Gracias chamo si me sirvió tu ayuda.